# Why doesn't fscanf convert set and then char?

Tags: c, scanf

If the file `foobar.txt` contains the text `foobar`, then in the following code

```
char s[16], c;
fp = fopen("foobar.txt", "r");
fscanf(fp, "%[f]s%c", s, &c);
```

`fscanf` returns 1 and not 2 as expected.

Whereas if I split the call to `fscanf`:

```
fscanf(fp, "%[f]s", s);
fscanf(fp, "%c", &c);
```

then both return 1 as expected.

Why doesn't the single `fscanf` work?

Comment: `"%[f]s%c"` remove `s` --> `"%[f]%c"`

Comment: Scan sets are a separate conversion specifier, not a modifier to `%s` — see [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) for example.

Comment: Thank you I did not RTFM carefully enough.  Please make it into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `s` shouldn't be there, instead it should be

```
fscanf("%[f]%c", s, &c);
```

When `scanf()` finds the `s` in the format but not in the input it stops and returns `1` because up until then 1 argument matched.

The thing is, the `s` is not part of the format, the `[]` is the format specifier and it only contains a single character the `f`, so you should read the documentation more carefully and you can confirm that the `s` is not required for the format specifier, and in fact `fscanf()` is considering it as part of the requested input, but it's not there because after the `f` there is a `o`, try `fsobar`.

In the second case, it also stops and does not consume any character after the `f` and then the second call consumes a single character thus both return `1` correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `s` and modify it as follows.

```
fscanf("%[f]%c", s, &c);
```

In the first case, when `fscanf()` cannot find `s` in the input it stops and returns 1. In the second case, as you mentioned, its obvious that `fscanf()` will return 1.